# Using Spatial Analyst Geoprocessing functions in ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, spatial-analyst

I'm trying to run some geoprocessing functions in ArcObjects.  Some of the tools I want to use are part of the spatial analyst extension.  In 9.3.1 it was fairly straightforward to follow the documentation and execute geoprocessing tools in ArcObjects.  In ArcGIS it seems all the spatial analyst tools are only available through the arcpy.sa site package.  The tools still exist in the arctoolbox with a standard parameter for the output raster.  But all the documentation on the tools show the output as a raster object not a standard parameter.  When I try and execute the tool in ArcObjects it fails because it doesn't expect a return and as far as I can tell there is no parameter for the output raster.  Anyone trying to run spatial analyst geoprocessing tools from ArcObjects in 10?

Comment: I am not sure why you cannot run the Geoprocessing tools using ArcObjects. Can you share the code that you are running? If that is not possible, can you run the code given in [AndOne's reply](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2318/how-do-you-use-spatial-analyst-geoprocessing-functions-in-arcobjects-in-arcgis-10/2780#2780)?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the (relatively) new Geoprocessor class?

```
Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
RasterToPolygon r2p = new RasterToPolygon();
r2p.in_raster = "myRaster";
r2p.out_polygon_features = "myPolygon";
r2p.simplify = "NO_SIMPLIFY";
IGeoProcessorResult result = gp.Execute(r2p, null) as IGeoProcessorResult;
```

If you look at the [geoprocessor library of AO](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/0047/0047000453n1000000.htm) you will find the Spatial Analyst tools, too.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is to use existing Spatial Analyst's functions, and the sole motivation in doing this is to automate your geo processing through scripting, then i would suggest using the `arcpy` Python framework, as it is a lot easier to work with.

Comment: I am coming to that conclusion as well.  I have some other customizations I was planning on in ArcMap that will need to be done in ArcObjects and I wanted to keep everything in a single toolbar.  But geoprocessing and spatial analyst tasks are indeed quicker to code in python.  Thanks very much for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought; you could build a model then run it from within a procedure.